# separate smooth in and out zoom

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've only been working in unity for a few days and have the following problem that I don't know how to make the zoom in and zoom out smooth without the rest running smooth as well. Nevertheless I want to keep the function that I can decide if the rest can be smooth or not. As mentioned before, the main problem is that I don't know how to Smoothen the zoom in and zoom out ONLY.   When I start the project with my current code, it feels like my mouse's dpi is pretty high. Also, every action is smooth, which I don't want either. I would be very happy about help.

Vace :)

```cs
if (thirdperson)
        {
            yaw += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity;
            pitch -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity;
            pitch = Mathf.Clamp(pitch, pitchMinMax.x, pitchMinMax.y);

            // out
            if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") < 0)
            {
                if (dstFromTarget < 12)
                {
                    dstFromTarget++;
                }
            }

            //in
            if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") > 0)
            {
                if (dstFromTarget > 2)
                {
                    dstFromTarget--;
                }
            }

            currentRotation = Vector3.SmoothDamp(currentRotation, new Vector3(pitch, yaw), ref rotationSmoothVelocity, rotationSmoothTime);
            transform.eulerAngles = currentRotation;

            Vector3 test = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, target.position - transform.forward * dstFromTarget, ref zoomSmoothVelocity, zoomSmoothTime);

            transform.position = new Vector3(test.x, test.y, test.z);
        }
```

Comment: try using `transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(pitch.yaw);` to bypass your first call to `Vector3.SmoothDamp`.

Comment: thanks for your answer. with me it's still the same that moving the camera to the left and right is smooth, which i don't want. i just want to have the zoom in and out of the camera smooth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Use the float version of `Vector3.SmoothDamp`: [`Mathf.SmoothDamp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.SmoothDamp.html).

Use it to find a smoothed target for `dstFromTarget`. change `zoomSmoothVelocity` to a float and initialize a current zoom variable to the same value as you initialize `dstFromTarget`.

Then, you can just assign the target you had for your `Vector3.SmoothDamp` directly to the camera's position.

Use `transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(pitch.yaw);` to bypass your first call to `Vector3.SmoothDamp`

I'd also recommend using `Mathf.Clamp` to keep your zoom in a valid range.

Altogether, this may look like this:

```
private float zoomSmoothVelocity = 0f;
private float curZoom = 6f; // however dstFromTarget is initialized 

// ...

if (thirdperson)
{
    yaw += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity;
    pitch -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity;
    pitch = Mathf.Clamp(pitch, pitchMinMax.x, pitchMinMax.y);

    // out
    if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") < 0)
    {
        dstFromTarget++;
    }

    //in
    if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") > 0)
    {
        dstFromTarget--;
    }
    
    dstFromTarget = Mathf.Clamp(dstFromTarget, 2f, 12f);

    transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(pitch, yaw);

    curZoom =  Mathf.SmoothDamp(curZoom , dstFromTarget, ref zoomVelocity , zoomSmoothTime);

    transform.position = target.position - transform.forward * curZoom;
}
```